# node remove a directory after gzipping it

Tags: node.js, gzip

I got the following code from SO to gzip a directory:

```
fstream.Reader({'path':'mydir','type':'Directory'}).pipe(tar.Pack()).pipe(zlib.Gzip()).pipe(fstream.Writer({'path': 'mygz.tar.gz'}));
```

And to delete a directory:

```
rm_rf('mydir',function(error){});
```

I need to put them together, so that I can gzip a dir and delete the original directory. To do this, I need to find a way to listen to the last `pipe()` event. Can someone help me with how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `end` reader event. It fires when the piping of the reader is finished:

```
var reader = fstream.Reader({'path':'mydir','type':'Directory'});

reader.pipe(tar.Pack()).pipe(zlib.Gzip()).pipe(fstream.Writer({'path': 'mygz.tar.gz'}));

reader.on('end', function() {
  rm_rf('mydir',function(error){});
});
```